# Extracting a variable from a permalink

Tags: urls, author, variables

I used the "Edit Author Slug" plugin to change the author base to /newbase .

In the functions.php file, I added a new node to the toolbar (View Profile) that when clicked points to ../newbase/johndoe (johndoe is the author slug)

I'm using the author.php page as the /profile and will show some user information.

If the user is logged in and clicks in the "View Profile" link, I have no problem. Inside author.php I can use  $current_user->user_login and get all the information.

My problem is for those not logged in or, let say I have a page displaying users and I click on their link which looks like .../profile/mrsmith - I cannot use $current_user .

I would like to somehow pass a variable (maybe query_vars, I don't know) to author.php (/profile) or to extract the "mrsmith" from the URL and the inside author.php I can look up that user in the database and show the data I want.

I appreciate your help on this. Maybe is very easy but I have struggle for 2 days and have tried multiple things and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the queried author in `author.php` with [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object):

```
$author = get_queried_object();
echo $author->ID;

$author_data = get_object_vars( $author->data );

echo $author_data['display_name'];
echo $author_data['user_url'];
echo $author_data['user_email'];
```

Comment: Hello Milo, I was able to get it to work with a piece of your code. That is $author = get_queried_object(); - with that I go the id and plot it into get_userdata( $userid ) - I did't have to mess up with anything else. Thank you very much.

Comment: Joe, you should mark the answer as accepted. Please read the [About](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about) and [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) pages to learn how this site works.